# Delphi Databank Grid does not refresh in time

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I know I'm dumb, but I don't get why my DB grid doesn't refresh in time. I created a Databank to secure some information, and created a Forms, which can INSERT Items into the Databank.
To test if it works properly I added a Button to execute my procedure "Refresh". The Problem I have is that it does not Refresh my DBGrid when the button is Clicked, but when I Click the Buttons many times. I'm new to Databases, so please have mercy.

```
`//Unit Form1

procedure TForm1.Refresh;
begin
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT ID, Name, size, amount FROM ITEMS');
        ADOQuery1.Open;
        DataSource1.DataSet.Refresh;
        DataSource1.DataSet.Open;
        ADOQuery1.Active:= false;
        ADOQuery1.Active:= true;
        DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
        DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Open;
end;


//Unit Form2

procedure TForm2.btnSafeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
try
    Form1.Refresh;
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO ITEMS(name, Amount, description, size, IMGLINK) VALUES (:CT, :SZ, :NA, DS:)';
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('NA').Value:= txtName.Text;
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('CT').Value:= strtoint(lblCT.caption);
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('DS').Value:= txtDescription.Text;
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('SZ').Value:= strtoint(cbSize.Text);
finally
    ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
    Self.Close;
end;`
```

Comment: There are one or two issues with the code, you should check out. Firstly, there is no explicit link offered between DBGrid1, DataSource1 and ADOQuery1. We can guess that DBGrid1.Datasource := DataSource1 and DatSource1.DataSet := ADOQuery1... so only minor issue. Secondly you use two forms and subsequently two queries named ADOQuery1? As a beginner I would concentrate on solving a problem using one form first and then perhaps extrapolate. Thirdly and more importantly: The ADOQuery1.ExecSQL statement should not be included in the finally clause. And lastly you refresh and open way to often.

Comment: In short: read the fine tutorials provided by Embarcadero: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/How_To_Perform_Database_Procedures

Comment: It  makes absolutely no sense to refresh the data from a SELECT and then **immediately close that query and use it for an INSERT**. You reload the grid, then immediately disconnect the data that it is using. Use separate queries for your SELECT and INSERT. Also, you should rename your `Refresh` to something more meaningful, like `RefreshData`. You're not refreshing the form. I second @Sherlock70's recommendation that you read the database tutorials provided in the documentation to gain some understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: I have a dataSource-, a ADOQuery-, and a connection component in my Form1. I have set the DataSet of my datasource to my Query, my Query is connected to my Connection-component.  I deleted most of my Code from my Refresh, and just wrote Query.Requary. My DBGrid now loads my new inserted data , but only after 5 Seconds after the insert. I have no Idea why, because I opened the database on Access right after the insert, and my data was already inserted, but my grid does not show it right away.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found a solution. My `TObjects` I used to write the data in, were normal edits. I now changed them to DBedit and gave them the column for each data, with the data source set to my query. To add something in the grid I just wrote query.insert to insert an empty dataset, then I showed my form2 to write in the DBedits.